# if !empty statement crashes my site

Tags: php, if-statement

I have the following if statment:

```
<a href="#"
   title="<?php the_sub_field('points_description'); ?>"
   class="<?php if(!empty(the_sub_field('points_description'))) {
                  echo 'point-tooltip'; } ?>">
```

If I just include the echo part the site displays, but when I add the if part  (checking if the function is `""`) the site just displays blank.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you change it to the_sub_field("point_description")!="" ?

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: @the_red_baron strange, when I do that the class is replaced by the content of the function `the_sub_field('points_description'); ?>`.

Comment: Are you additionally confused about function *return* values and the function *outputting* something?

Answer (score 6):

The empty function only works with vars.

> empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)).

Comment: is right, you need to put the_sub_field('points_description')) to a variable first then try if it'll work

Comment: Or in this case don't use `empty()` at all. It can be so nice to read: `echo the_sub_field('points_description')) ?: 'no points_description';`

Answer (score -2):

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) only works with variables as this is function also checks that a function is defined.

To make the code below executable

```
// doesn't work :(
if(!empty(a_function($var)))
    do_stuff();
```

you have to store the result from a_function() into a temporary variable

```
//works :D
$temp = a_function($var);
if(!empty($temp))
    do_stuff();
```

Comment: That's just nonsense. You simply do not need `empty` for functions, because `empty` is solving a problem that does not need solving in a function context. Just `if (a_function($var))` works fine.

Comment: Functionally you're 100% correct, but the difference in readability is huge.

Comment: Really?! Do `if (a_function($var) == true)` then if you have problems with boolean expressions. IMO it makes less sense, since a function can't be "empty". Its return value can be *truthy* or *falsey* though.

Comment: The fact that "hello" fuzzily equals true in PHP doesn't make it readable. I don't have a problem with boolean expressions, I have a problem with boolean expressions containing non-booleans.

Comment: Then that's something you simply need to get used to. You can still write hyper explicit `=== true` comparisons if you want to. That doesn't change the fact that what `empty` is used for simply does not apply to function calls. Please see the abovelinked Guide to PHP's isset and empty for details.

Comment: Readability and functionality is two different concerns. I understand how and why empty works as it does, but I don't agree in that design decision. This is however far too offtopic, but I thank you for your input.